# PHP - Checking checkboxes if their value is in array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have 2 arrays, I take 1 string out of the first array and check if its in the second array, if it is then the checkbox is already checked. My code does check the checkbox but it also creates an unchecked version of the same checkbox. My if statement is in a foreach loop so the problem might be in the order, but cant seem to figure it out.

My code:

```
<?php foreach ($zamestnanec_item as $key => $value):?>
              [Other codes here]
              <?php foreach ($myukony_item as $key => $value3):
              if(in_array($value['Nazov'],$value3)): ?>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ukony[]" value="<?php echo $value['ID_ukon'] ?>" checked="checked"><?php echo $value['Nazov'] ?>
              <?php else: ?>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ukony[]" value="<?php echo $value['ID_ukon'] ?>" ><?php echo $value['Nazov'] ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
       <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Solved it myself:

```
  <?php foreach ($myukony_item as $key => $value3):
                        if(in_array($value['Nazov'],$value3)): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ukony[]" value="<?php echo $value['ID_ukon'] ?>" checked="checked"><?php echo $value['Nazov'] ?>
                        <?php  break; else:
                            if( $key == ( count( $myukony_item ) - 1 ) ):?>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ukony[]" value="<?php echo $value['ID_ukon'] ?>" ><?php echo $value['Nazov'] ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif;
                        ?>
                       <?php endforeach;?>
```

The unchecked box should only be added after it iterated through the entire inner foreach loop and didnt find a match.

Comment: You could shorten it by using checked ="<?php echo ( in_array( $value['Nazov'],$value3 ) ? 'checked' : '' ); ?>" in replace of checked="checked", that would remove the need for two lines of the same code and clean things up a little.

Comment: I don't see any way it could create both versions of the same checkbox. Either the `if` or `else` executes, never both. Could there be duplicates in `$myukony_item`?

Comment: I am also not getting both at time. Crossverified by creating 2 arrays

Comment: I dont get it either. Both those arrays are populated by data from a table, where the array "zamestnanec_item"  has all of the "acts" and "myukony_item" has only the acts where the ID of the employee equals to the one where I clicked. So the 2nd array contains some of the rows from the first array.

Comment: I think the issue is the loop in loop.  Loop 2s  1st item in array is being checked with Loop 1s  1st item, then Loop 2s 2nd item in array checked with Loop 1s 1st item ..this is why duplicates are being created. In the first case it equals, but not the second. I need to somehow fix this.